# Oracle Forms post-rollback for check multiple detail block

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

Shortly; i have multiple detail blocks related to each other like a tree so i needed to check every blocks has parent and child. (It's complicated).

So i decided best way to control that, post and rollback if data is not correct.

This is the code in my `KEY-COMMIT` trigger and it runs before the `commit`:

```
if :kampanyaTanim.katmanKod = 1 then
    post;
    checkSection(:kampanyaTanim.seq);
    rollback;
end if;
```

and this is the `checkSection` procedure:

```
PROCEDURE checkSection(p_kampSeq number) IS
v_skor number;
v_yas number;
BEGIN
select count(s.skorSeq)
  ,count(y.yasSeq)
into v_skor
  ,v_yas
  bla.bla my control query


if v_skor <> v_yas then
    rollback;
    messagebox('test');
    raiseUserError('Segment hatasý! Bütün skor aralýklarý için yaþ aralýðý tanýmlanmalýdýr.');
end if;
exception when others then
    messageBox(sqlerrm);
    ShowMessage('',True,DEF_MESSAGE_HANDLER);
END;
```

so when i test this procedure test messagebox works fine but then **100501 non-ORACLE** exception pops up (twice) then the forms close. I have no idea what's wrong and i think `rollback` causes the error but don't know how.
So i could use some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: perhaps `messageBox(dbms_utility.format_call_stack)` might help.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Error says can't call builtin routines remotely do i have to change its parameters?

Comment: seems you call a procedure from a remote db, don't you? Try to call by regular SQL SELECT statement instead.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan No i don't. There is only a select query in this code, all the other procedures i'm using defined in forms under program units